# how to display a file using react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

So, I have those "cards" to which are attached files.

I want to be able to display the content of these files (when possible; I do not expect to show binary files obviously, but text, pdf, images,...) to the user.

Upon a longPress on an attachment, the openAttachment() function is be called. That function downloads the file from the server if necessary and then (tries to) open it:

```
   // Opens an attachment
    const openAttachment = async (attachment) => {
        try {
            // Download file if not already done
            const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.cacheDirectory + attachment.name)
            let uri
            if (!fileInfo.exists) {
                console.log('Downloading attachment')
                resp = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                    server.value + `/index.php/apps/deck/api/v1.0/boards/${route.params.boardId}/stacks/${route.params.stackId}/cards/${route.params.cardId}/attachments/${attachment.id}`,
                    FileSystem.cacheDirectory + attachment.name,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': token.value
                        },
                    },
                )
                console.log(resp)
                uri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(resp.uri)

            } else {
                console.log('File already in cache')
                uri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(fileInfo.uri)
            }
            console.log('Opening file ' + uri)
            Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
        } catch {
            Toast.show({
                type: 'error',
                text1: i18n.t('error'),
                text2: error.message,
            })
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

The issue always arrise at the `Sharing.shareAsync(uri);` line: Whatever I put there, it fails:

1. **Sharing.shareAsync(uri)** does not seem to be supported on my platform: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/
2. **Linking.openURL(uri)** does not support the `file://` scheme (the uri is in the form `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C1CB402-5ED1-4E17-B907-46111AE3FB7C/Library/Caches/test.pdf`)
3. **await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(uri)** (from `expo-web-browser`) does not seem to be able to open local files

How am I supposed to do to display those files? Anyone has an idea?

Cyrille

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using react-native-file-viewer

```
   // Opens an attachment
    const openAttachment = async (attachment) => {
        try {
            // Download file if not already done
            const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "attachment.name")
            let uri
            if (!fileInfo.exists) {
                console.log('Downloading attachment')
                const resp = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                    server.value + `/index.php/apps/deck/api/v1.0/boards/${route.params.boardId}/stacks/${route.params.stackId}/cards/${route.params.cardId}/attachments/${attachment.id}`,
                    FileSystem.cacheDirectory + attachment.name,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': token.value
                        },
                    },
                )
                console.log(resp)
                uri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(resp.uri)

            } else {
                console.log('File already in cache')
                uri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(fileInfo.uri)
            }
            console.log('opening file', uri)
            FileViewer.open(uri)
        } catch(error) {
            Toast.show({
                type: 'error',
                text1: i18n.t('error'),
                text2: error.message,
            })
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```